# Андроид сохранение текста

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы вписанный текст в готовом приложении, сохранялся при выходе? К примеру у меня есть готовое приложение "Дневник". При входе в которое вам просто открывают несколько ImageViev и посреди EditText. Как мне сделать чтобы вся информация вписанная в EditText сохранялась автоматически, а при повторном входе в приложение вся информация написанная ранее оставалась EditText в том виде в котором её оставили?

Comment: Cмотря какие это данные, сколько их и будет ли их больше

Comment: Данные исключительно текст! И да по возможности заходить и снова менять их. Поэтому, но можно определить границу в 1000 символов, больше не потребуется.

Comment: Изучайте работу с файловой системой Android и жизненный цикл `Activity`.В данный момент постановка вопроса слишком уж общая и потому ничего больше посоветовать не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сохранения текста вы можете использовать различные методы. Одним из вариантов - является [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). Пример класса:

```
public class UserPreferences {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static UserPreferences userPreferences;


    public static UserPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
       if (userPreferences == null) {
        userPreferences = new UserPreferences(context);
       }
       return userPreferences;
    }

    private UserPreferences(Context context){
       sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedSettings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void storeUserVote(String vote){
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putString("storeUserVote", vote);
       editor.commit();
    }
    public String getUserVote(){
       return sharedPreferences.getString("storeUserVote", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое